# Setting up a timer for game

Tags: java

I want to make a fruit basket game. The idea here is that I want to draw fruits from the top of screen to bottom and I also want to do that with timer.I tried several ways but I got no result. Here is what I did but it's totally doing wrong.

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 while (getY() != 1500) {
        timer.schedule(new DrawFruit(frame, g, x) {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Panel.class.getResource(Consts.ImageResource.APRICOT_DIR)), 500, getY(), frame);
                frame.repaint();
                setY(getY() + 30);

            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```

and the DrawFruit Class

```
abstract class DrawFruit extends TimerTask {
private JFrame jFrame;
private Graphics g;
private int x;

public JFrame getJFrame() {
    return jFrame;
}

public void setJFrame(JFrame jFrame) {
    this.jFrame = jFrame;
}

public Graphics getG() {
    return g;
}

public void setG(Graphics g) {
    this.g = g;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public DrawFruit(JFrame frame , Graphics g , int x){
    setJFrame(frame);
    setG(g);
    setX(x);
}


@Override
public void run() {

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What you are doing will lead to problems down the road... A timer-based solution is a naive implementation for animation loops. I very strongly recommend that you look into **Delta-Time loops**, and why they are used for animations.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT be using looping code. The point of a Timer is that it replaces the loop. All a Timer does is generate an event at your specified time interval. So when the event is generated you just adjust the "Y" value and repaint the component.

However, you should not be using a TimerTask for this.

Swing components should be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Therefore you should be using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Read the tutorial for a working example to get you started.